# Using macports to install py25-pil is installing just a ton of unrelated stuff

Tags: python, macports

It's been going for an age and things I have seen scroll past include such gems as libX11, ncurses and my personal favorite: perl5!

Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

python25 is a rather kitchen-sink build.

It depends on tk, which depends on Xft2 … that's where some X11 stuff comes from.

There's [a script available](http://trac.macports.org/browser/contrib/port-rdeps) to show all dependencies involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit the portfile to remove the dependency on `tk`, which is the main culprit.

```
sudo port edit python25
```

(Look for `port:tk` in the `depends_lib` section.)

I did this for awhile to keep MacPorts version of Getmail, but in the end, I just began to manually install Getmail instead.

I love both MacPorts and Fink, but I hate how quick they are to drag in whole new Python, Perl or Ruby installations. As a contrast, you might check out [Rudix](http://rudix.org/). It's a much thinner environment, though it doesn't support as many packages as MacPorts or Fink.

Comment: Manually editing the Portfiles is a rather futile effort as the changes will be wiped out after a sync or selfupdate.  If you find having tk being included to be a problem, file a ticket with the maintainers.

Comment: @Nerdling: as far as I can tell, the maintainers made a conscious decision to include tk. I don't think it's coming out. I agree that it's tedious to edit the portfile over and over, and so I eventually just installed Getmail manually (as I say in my post).

Comment: You could try filing a patch that adds a `no_tk` variant. Might not get accepted, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Macports installs in a separate location, I think /opt, so you don't have to worry about polluting your system.